# How to compile plutus source code locally?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, cabal, nix, nix-shell

I'm trying to compile the Plutus source code locally, I tried `cabal build` in `nix-shell`,

getting this error

```
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, libsystemd-journal,
lobemo-scribe-systemd, Win32-network
```

This is the full error I got[image: error]

I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04LTS OS

Thanks,

Please let me know if my approach is wrong.

Comment: Please give more details of the system and the steps you completed. Did you check the documentation at https://docs.plutus-community.com/?

Comment: Yes, I followed the documentation and installed Nix(Single-user) and then followed this https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/CabalBuild.html and when I did cabal build ended up in that error

Comment: Did you execute cabal update first?

Comment: Yes, this was the output
```Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Package list of hackage.haskell.org is up to date at index-state 2021-08-16T12:54:02Z```

Comment: Win32-network - dependency not fulfilled is an indication that if there is a problem in the checked-out version. Would you mind checking with the version used in that particular lecture? I had faced the same issue.

Comment: I see you're using Week 1 of the Pioneer Program.  Did you check out the correct plutus tag `(in plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01/cabal.project)` before running `nix-shell` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be having issues resolving the dependencies for that particular build of Plutus. In fact, all Cardano builds depend on `libsystemd` (on Linux).

If you have incompatible versions of `libsystemd` and `libsystemd-journal` you get the rejection that you're having in regards to the dependencies. It appears Plutus also depends on these packages.

Please see the following link: [cardano-haskell.README.md#system-setup](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-haskell/blob/master/README.md#system-setup).

I would try:

```
sudo apt get install libsystemd-dev
```

Then, try and reboot a terminal window, checkout to the correct branch within the Plutus.git repository.

Ensure you checkout the tag provided within the plutus-pioneer-program.git/code/week01/cabal.project file, which I believe is `ea0ca4e9f9821a9dbfc5255fa0f42b6f2b3887c4`.

Then, you should be able to boot a Nix-Shell from the Plutus repo, navigate to `week01` and run `cabal build`.

If you've followed those steps (see below for some links that may be of help) and you're still having problems, we may need some more information.

Related links that may help:

- [Cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0 (conflict: pkg-config package libsodium-any, not found in the pkg-config database)](https://forum.cardano.org/t/cardano-crypto-class-2-0-0-conflict-pkg-config-package-libsodium-any-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-database/56203)
- [libsystemd-journal Packages For Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libsystemd-journal.pc&searchon=contents)
- [Cardano Haskell System Setup | Very Similar Issue (Same Package Conflict)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-haskell/blob/master/README.md#system-setup)

Answer (score 1):

Try in the nix-shell try this:

1. cabal update
2. cabal build

btw: first time building with cabal can take up some time